# Debug QEMU/KVM with gdb via a serial port

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, qemu, kvm

I tried to set-up `QEMU/KVM` to for `GDB` debuggin with a serial port and couldn't managed to make it work.

According to [QEMU GDB documentation](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/gdb.html)

> If you want to specify which TCP port to use or to use something other
> than TCP for the gdbstub connection, use the -gdb dev option instead
> of -s.

Here are my attempts:

***I***. I looked at available `tty` devices and picked up the first one `/dev/ttyS0`

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -gdb /dev/ttyS0 -S
```

In `GDB` I tried

```
(gdb) target remote /dev/ttyS0
get_tty_state failed: Input/output error
set_tty_state failed: Input/output error
Remote debugging using /dev/ttyS0
Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: Input/output error.
```

***II***. Create a chardev and pass it to `-gdb` option

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -chardev serial,id=ser0,path=/dev/ttyS0 -gdb /dev/ttyS0 -S
```

`GDB` responds with the same error msg:

```
(gdb) target remote /dev/ttyS0
get_tty_state failed: Input/output error
set_tty_state failed: Input/output error
Remote debugging using /dev/ttyS0
Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: Input/output error.
```

***III.*** Pass a chardev id to the `-gdb` option

```
$ sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -chardev serial,id=ser0,path=/dev/ttyS0 -gdb ser0 -S  
qemu-system-x86_64: -gdb ser0: 'ser0' is not a valid char driver
```

This way `QEMU` does not start at all.

**QUESTION:** What is the correct way to set-up QEMU GDB debugging via a serial port?